# How do i mask the jenkins pasword in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am having a jenkins pipeline job which has username and password as string and password parameters. i want to get the values from the parameter and mask the values so that i can use it pipeline for accessing my tool. can someone help on this please

Comment: Jenkins should take care it.  If you choose parameter type to `Password`, Jenkins will mask it as `***` in console output.  Can you show your pipeline code.

Comment: when i am using the varaible in jenkins pipeline teh password is printed in cleartext

Comment: I'm wrong, Jenkins not mask Password parameter,  but Credentials Binding in console output.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use:

- the [JENKINS EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), which beings [Inject passwords to the build as environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36816029/6309)
- or the [JENKINS Mask Passwords Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin)

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/46335226/config-after.png?version=1&modificationDate=1283327974000&api=v2]

With pipelines, you would use [an array of secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52830296/6309).